# eel処理がモック化出来ない

Tags: python, javascript, pytest

ご存知でしたら、ご教授下さい。

eelで下記jsで定義したメソッドがあります。

```
eel.expose(view_log_js)
function view_log_js(text){
         result.value += text + "\n"
}
```

これをpython側で呼び出しています。

```
@eel.expose
def fetch_items() 
    view_log_js("テスト")
```

fetch_itemsのテスト処理をpytestで作成したいのですが、eel.view_log_jsをmock化できないです。。

下記ではeelにそんなメソッドないとエラーが吐かれます。

```
mocker.patch('eel.view_log_js', return_value="TEST")
```

元々eelに含まれていないのは分かるのですが、js側でバインドした関数を認識させる方法は無いでしょうか？

下記URL(公式?)のコードを読んでも出来そうにないです。。
https://github.com/python-eel/Eel/tree/master/tests

Comment: [githubリポジトリトップの説明](https://github.com/python-eel/Eel)だと各`eel.expose(...)`の後ろにセミコロンが付いていますが、その有無では？

Comment: 返信が遅れて申し訳ありません。。
ご回答ありがとうございます。

セミコロンを付けましたが、改善しない様です。。
色々試してみます。

Comment: eelが動作しているらしい記事が参考になるかも。[\[Python\] EelをつかってGUIアプリを開発する（基礎）](https://sinyblog.com/python/python-eel-001/), [Python – Eel で GUI アプリケーションを作成する方法](https://pystyle.info/python-create-gui-application-with-eel/) あるいはeelが如何とかよりモック側の使い方かも？ [\[Python\] pytest mocker.patchがやっと動いたので、わかったことを勢いだけで書いておく](https://qiita.com/sengoku/items/a9e67b2ec1233b0f2fe0), [Pythonのunittestのmock.patchでハマった話...](https://www.denzow.me/entry/2017/12/17/225453), [\[Python\] pytest でモックを使う方法...](https://webbibouroku.com/Blog/Article/pytest-mock), [【pytest】モックの使い方まとめ](https://zenn.dev/re24_1986/articles/0a7895b1429bfa)